# Problem with the length of bonds in chemfig applying \charge command

Tags: chemfig

I am doing the chemical reaction shown in the image. As you can see, when I apply the \charge command in the second molecule, the length of the double bond decrease. Also, the charge in the second molecule misaligns the bonds from the center of the carbon atom.  Could you give me any suggestions? The code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
    \schemestart
    \chemfig[atom sep=2em]{C(-[2])(-[6])(-[4]C(-[4](*6(=-=-=-)))(=[6]O))-}
    \arrow{->[$h\nu$]}\chemfig[atom sep=2em]{\Charge{45=\.}{C}(=[6]O)(-[4](*6(=-=-=-)))}
    \+
    \chemfig[atom sep=2em]{\Charge{135=\.}{C}(-[2])(-[6])-}
    \schemestop
\end{document}
```

[image: Chemical reaction]

Comment: try `\charge` with lower case. Is that more like you want it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\charge` places the charge outside of the bounding box while `\Charge` places the charges into the bounding box.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
    charge:
    \schemestart
    \chemfig[atom sep=2em]{C(-[2])(-[6])(-[4]C(-[4](*6(=-=-=-)))(=[6]O))-}
    \arrow{->[$h\nu$]}\chemfig[atom sep=2em]{\charge{45=\.}{C}(=[6]O)(-[4](*6(=-=-=-)))}
    \+
    \chemfig[atom sep=2em]{\charge{135=\.}{C}(-[2])(-[6])-}
    \schemestop

    Charge:
    \schemestart
    \chemfig[atom sep=2em]{C(-[2])(-[6])(-[4]C(-[4](*6(=-=-=-)))(=[6]O))-}
    \arrow{->[$h\nu$]}\chemfig[atom sep=2em]{\Charge{45=\.}{C}(=[6]O)(-[4](*6(=-=-=-)))}
    \+
    \chemfig[atom sep=2em]{\Charge{135=\.}{C}(-[2])(-[6])-}
    \schemestop
\end{document}
```

[image]